# Flutter Exception caught by gesture. No MediaQuery widget found inside showModalBottomSheet

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Why I can't use showModalBottomSheet inside floatingActionButton? It just keeps showing me this error:

```
I/flutter (16368): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (16368): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (16368): No MediaQuery widget found.
I/flutter (16368): MyApp widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.
I/flutter (16368): The specific widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was:
I/flutter (16368):   MyApp
I/flutter (16368): The ownership chain for the affected widget is: "MyApp ← [root]"
I/flutter (16368): Typically, the MediaQuery widget is introduced by the MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget at the top of
I/flutter (16368): your application widget tree.
I/flutter (16368): 
I/flutter (16368): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (16368): #0      debugCheckHasMediaQuery.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:211:7)
I/flutter (16368): #1      debugCheckHasMediaQuery (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:223:4)
I/flutter (16368): #2      showModalBottomSheet (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:469:10)
I/flutter (16368): #3      _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_happy_habits/main.dart:32:29)
I/flutter (16368): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './models/home.dart';
import 'models/progress.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    Home(),
    Progress(),
    Progress(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Demo')),
        body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () { showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Text('Modal bottom sheet', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30));
            });
          }
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          notchMargin: 4.0,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Home");
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedPage = 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Progress");
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedPage = 1;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Its because, the `showModalBottomSheet` tries to access the ancestor of type `MaterialApp` from the given `context`.

Use `Builder` widget to get new `context` with `MaterialApp` ancestor or Separate your `MaterialAapp` and `Scaffold` widgets into separate widgets.

Using `Builder` :

```
floatingActionButton: Builder(
  builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () { showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Text('Modal bottom sheet', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30));
          });
      }
  ),
),
```

Comment: But why? Why we need the `Builder`? I read through some tutorials and nobody mentions this. Like here: [Bottom Sheet Tutorial](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-5-bottom-sheet-2d56bf9f3bc)

Comment: @Gabriel when you call `showModalBottomSheet()` you will be passing a `context` object. This context is used to find the ancestor which is `MaterialApp`.

Comment: @Gabriel In the questing, you can see he passed the `context` which is got from the `build(BuildContext context)`. It doesn't contain any `MaterialApp` ancestor.

Comment: @Gabriel But inside an the build method there is an `MaterialApp` widget used. So we can get an new `context` using `Builder` widget, then we can pass that context to `showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: @Gabriel [Bottom Sheet Tutorial](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-5-bottom-sheet-2d56bf9f3bc) here the `MaterialApp` widget not placed inside `MyHomePage ` widget, but placed in separate stateless widget. here `MyHomePage ` is kind of acting like `Builder` widget and gives new `context` via `build` method.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you!

Comment: This should be right answer...Thank you for save my time

Answer (score 4):

I've got a solution. I don't know if it's the best but it works. The showModalBottomSheet should not have the same context as the materialapp, so it must be separated in a statelesswidget as you can see in this example.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Modal bottom sheet')),
        body: new Center(
          child: new RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return new Container(
                  child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                    child: new Text('This is the modal bottom sheet. Click anywhere to dismiss.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        fontSize: 24.0
                      )
                    )
                  )
                );
              });
            }
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the  showModalBottomSheet inside Builder() it works with me

```
body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          (questionindex < question.length)
              ? Quiz(question, questionindex, nextquestion)
              : Result(playagain),
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Show Modal Bottom Sheet'),
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Wrap(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.share),
                            title: Text('Share'),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.copy),
                            title: Text('Copy Link'),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
                            title: Text('Edit'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).